# Spring boot post method is not working

Tags: spring, rest, curl, spring-boot

For the below controller my "GET" method is working but my post method is not working . Th error is "POST method not supported"

My create method is working fine but update is not working.

and this is the curl command for my testing:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{
id: 2,
title: "My first note title update",
note: "My First Note update",
createTime: 1461737231000,
lastUpdateTime: 1461737231000
}
]' -u "a@a.a":a localhost:8080/update

```
@RestController
public class GotPrintController {

    @Autowired
    private NotesRepository notesRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/createnotes")
    @Transactional
    public Notes create() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("auth.getName::"+auth.getName());
        Notes notes = new Notes();
        notes.setCreateTime(new Date());
        notes.setLastUpdateTime(new Date());
        notes.setNote("My First Note");
        notes.setTitle("My first note title");
        notesRepository.save(notes);
        return notes;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/readnotes")
    @Transactional
    public List<Notes> read(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("auth.getName::"+auth.getName());
        User users = userRepository.findByEmailId(auth.getName());
        List<Notes> notes = (List<Notes>) users.getNotes();
        return notes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("auth.getName::"+auth.getName());
        User users = userRepository.findByEmailId(auth.getName());
        List<Notes> notes = (List<Notes>) users.getNotes();
        for (Notes notes2 : notes) {
            if(notes2.getId() == id){
                notesRepository.delete(id);
                return "success";
            }
        }
        return "failure";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Content-type: application/*")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Notes note){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("auth.getName::"+auth.getName());
        User users = userRepository.findByEmailId(auth.getName());
        List<Notes> notes = (List<Notes>) users.getNotes();
        for (Notes notes2 : notes) {
            if(note.getId() == notes2.getId()){
                // note belongs to user update it
                notesRepository.save(note);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(note, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT); 
    }

}
```

This is log when trying to hot POST method from curl

2016-04-27 13:15:36.927  INFO 14755 --- [           main] com.gotprint.GotprintApplication         : Started GotprintApplication in 18.481 seconds (JVM running for 23.399)
2016-04-27 13:15:47.298  INFO 14755 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-04-27 13:15:47.298  INFO 14755 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-04-27 13:15:47.336  INFO 14755 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 38 ms
2016-04-27 13:15:47.433  WARN 14755 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Notes implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")  
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")  
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note; 

    @Column(name = "createTime")  
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "lastUpdateTime")  
    private Date lastUpdateTime;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdateTime() {
        return lastUpdateTime;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateTime(Date lastUpdateTime) {
        this.lastUpdateTime = lastUpdateTime;
    }
```

Comment: Change the headers property to `headers = "Content-type=application/*"`

Comment: What if you don't restrict the content type, or restrict it to "application/json" ? You can use `consumes =  "application/json"` instead of `headers = ...`

Comment: @Edd is right: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--

Comment: I used consumes = "application/json" and then I am getting Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.gotprint.entity.Notes out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: This is a another issue: you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes and [escape the inner quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855002/spring-data-rest-cannot-post-data-to-rest-api/36865453#36865453).

Comment: I was using curl in ubuntu but when I used double quotes it started working ...thank you guys...

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the

```
headers = "Content-type: application/*"
```

If you want to accept specific content type use the consumes property of the RequestMapping annotation.

Or of you want to use the headers property the syntax is:

```
headers = "Content-type=application/*"
```